# function with different types of variable

Tags: python, list, function

I have a little question. I am writing a mini game and I have a problem. I want to create function which returns a random number from range 100-990 given by user. I got error `'invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Get number'`. How to change this code to get around this problem. I know I can split this into 2 functions but I want to know how to write it in one function.

```
from typing import Final


def get_int_number_of_first_player(message: str, r_min: int, r_max: int):
    if r_min > int(message) > r_max:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect number')
    return int(input(f'{message}:\n'))


def main() -> None:
    value_min: Final = 100
    value_max: Final = 999
    get_int_number_of_first_player('Get number', value_min, value_max)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the string `'Get number'` that you pass to your function?

Comment: This line is creating issue `r_min > int(message) > r_max` because you are converting string to integer

Comment: To get a number from first player

Comment: How does a string `get a number from first player`?

Comment: If `message` is `"Get number"`, then `int(message)` is going to give you that exact error. I have no idea what you're trying to do, but in order for `int(message)` to work, `message` needs to be something like `"42"` - i.e., a string containing an integer.

Comment: Did you mean to write your function to get the `input()` first, and only then check the range with `r_min` and `r_max`?

Comment: Exactly, I wanted toto write a function that returns a user-given number with a given range(100-999)

Comment: So why do you perform the range check *before* the `input()` occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the input first and then check that value:

```py
def get_int_number_of_first_player(message: str, r_min: int, r_max: int):
    user_value = int(input(f'{message}:\n'))
    if not (r_min <= user_value <= r_max):
        raise ValueError('Incorrect number')
    return user_value
```

Note that if the user enters a string which cannot be converted to an `int`, then the `int()` function will raise a `ValueError`.